# Vector of base class pointers to access member functions from derived classes? The correct way?

Tags: c++

I would like to develop a kind of board game and currently manage the individual fields using std :: vector with pointers of the base class (see source code below).
The base class describes only one field without any special functionalities. I use derived classes to "model" individual types of fields.

However, later in the program (e.g. on the game controller side) I don't know how to access the member functions of the special fields. I think the following source code illustrates my concerns.

Here I wanted to "dynamically" trigger some actions based on the type of field.

I would be really grateful for any good advice, as it is a fundamental thing I think.

PS: Of course, it would be even more elegant to be able to completely omit the type information for the individual classes / special fields. It would be great if C ++ somehow knew which field / class it was.

THANKS!

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class cPlayer
{
public:
    std::string name;
};

// base class for all fields of the board (common parts)
// used also for special fields like GO, FREE PARKING, GO TO JAIL
class cField 
{
public:

    enum eType
    {
        STREET,
        RAIL,
        PRISON,
        CARD,
        SPECIAL
    };

    uint8_t     pos;
    std::string name{};
    eType type;   


    // strasse
    cField(const uint8_t& _pos, const std::string& _name, eType _type) :
        pos(pos),
        name(name),
        type(_type)
    {
    } 

    // strasse
    cField(const uint8_t& _pos, const std::string& _name) :
        pos(pos),
        name(name)
    {
    } 
};

// derived class for all street fields of the baord
class cStreet : cField
{
public:
    uint8_t     amountHouses;
    uint16_t    propertyPrice;
    cPlayer*    owner;

    cStreet(const uint8_t& _pos, const std::string& _name, uint16_t _propertyPrice) :
        cField(_pos, _name),
        propertyPrice(_propertyPrice)
    {
        type = cField::STREET;
        owner = nullptr;
    }

    std::string getStreetname(void)
    {
        return name;
    }
};

class cRailstation : cField
{
public:
    cPlayer*    owner;
    uint16_t    Price;

    cRailstation(const uint8_t& _pos, const std::string& _name, uint16_t _Price) :
        cField(_pos, _name),
        Price(_Price)
    {
        type = cField::RAIL;
        owner = nullptr;
    } 

    std::string getStationname(void)
    {
        return name;
    } 
};

class cPrison : cField
{
public:
    std::vector<cPlayer*> visitors;
    std::vector<cPlayer*> prisoners;
};

int main()
{
    
    uint8_t pos = 0;                // current field position on board
    std::string curFieldName{};     // current name of the field

    // add some players
    cPlayer player{"bob"};
    cPlayer enemy1{"stuart"};
    cPlayer enemy2{"kevin"};

    std::vector<cField*> fields;

    // build the board
    fields.push_back( new cField{pos++, std::string("GO"), cField::SPECIAL});
    fields.push_back( (cField*)new cStreet{pos++, std::string("Street 1"), 800} );
    fields.push_back( (cField*)new cStreet{pos++, std::string("Street 2"), 800} );
    fields.push_back( (cField*)new cRailstation{pos++, std::string("Railstation 1"), 300} );
    fields.push_back( (cField*)new cStreet{pos++, std::string("Street 3"), 800} );
    fields.push_back( (cField*)new cRailstation{pos++, std::string("Railstation 2"), 400} );
    fields.push_back( (cField*)new cStreet{pos++, std::string("Street 4"), 800} );
    fields.push_back( (cField*)new cStreet{pos++, std::string("Street 5"), 800} );
    fields.push_back( (cField*)new cStreet{pos++, std::string("Prison"), 800} );
    fields.push_back( (cField*)new cRailstation{pos++, std::string("Railstation 3"), 500} );
    // ...    

    // iterate over all fields on board
    for(auto field : fields)    
    {
        // find element by name
        if( field->type == cField::eType::SPECIAL) 
        {
            // here, we need only access to member function of the base class
        }
        else if( field->type == cField::eType::STREET)
        {
            // access to specific member functions of the derived class cStreet
            // for example
            //field->getOwner();
            //field->buildHouse();
            //field->getRent();
            curFieldName = (cStreet*)field->getStreetname();
        }
        else if( field->type == cField::eType::RAIL)
        {
            // access to specific member functions of the derived class cRailstation
            //field->getOwner();
            curFieldName = (cRailstation*)field->getStationame();
        }
        else if( field->type == cField::eType::PRISON)
        {
            // access to specific member functions of the derived class cPrsion
            //field->getPrisoners();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `using cField = std::variant<cStreet, cRailstation, cPrison/*, ..*/>;` might be more appropriate.

Comment: After reading your question and before peeking into your code: This is a typical scenario for *polymorphism*. Your base class should provide a *generic* interface of *virtual* functions that you can call. The deriving classes then override these functions to trigger the appropriate actions. Such generic functions for fields might comprise e.g. `enter` and `leave`, but that depends on what your game should actually be able to do.

Comment: "free parking", "go to jail", streets – sounds pretty much like Monopoly... Example: generic function is `action`, the override for GoToJail opens a dialog printing this message and places the character's piece to the Jail field, while a street field would open a buy dialog, if not yet sold, otherwise make the player pay the fee... From over all game management you'd just move the player's piece and call the `action` function of the move's end field – without knowing about the field's actual type (and replacing the entire if/else chaine you have how).

Comment: the "right" way to access derived members on a base pointer is to fix your design such that the base provides the necessary interface

Comment: "It would be great if C ++ somehow knew which field / class it was" -- it does, it's called polymorphism and there is also RTTI which you should do some research on. Both are intermediate to advanced topics though, so maybe you just need to follow your tutorial a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an approach called 'polymorphism':

You have a base class defining a *generic* interface that suffices all your needs for the overall game play mechanism:

```
class Field // recommendation: drop Hungarian notation!
{
public:
    virtual void action(Player& player) = 0;
    // pure virtual in this case
    // you might provide a default implementation instead
    // but if meaningful is up to you to decide
};
```

Then in your game runs all you need to do is to call this function:

```
// assuming std::vector:
player.position = (player.position + move) % fields.size();
fields[player.position].action();
```

– being totally unaware of the actual field type.

Now the concrete field types can override the `action` function *specifically*:

```
class GotoJail
{
public:
    void action(Player& player) override
    {
        // move player's piece to jail
    }
};

class Street
{
    Player* owner;
public:
    void action(Player& player) override
    {
        if(owner)
        {
            // make player pay the street's fee to owner
        }
        else
        {
            // offer player to buy the street
        }
    }
};
```

Jail is a good example for that this interface might not be sufficient; you might need a `preMoveAction` and a `postMoveAction`, as while being in jail you might have to offer the player to buy himself free.

`Field` instances might provide an instance of a specific `Data` type to the `Player` instances (conceptually similar to web cookies) storing some specific information, e.g. for jail if just being visiting or actually imprisoned – possibly even in form of a lambda or a function pointer that is just executed when it's the player's turn (maybe replacing `preMoveAction` so that you could have a single `action` again?) – possibilities are endless...